# Django -: adding multiple songs to playlist

Tags: python, django

i am creating the playlist to add songs in it....but i am unable to add multiple songs...i do not how to add.

models.py--->

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Song(models.Model):
    movie=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    song_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    artist=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year=models.IntegerField()
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    song_file=models.FileField(upload_to='songs/')



    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_name

class Playlist(models.Model):
    list_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song=models.ForeignKey(Song,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,default=None,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_name
```

views.py ---> in this i have addsongs_view function through which i am trying to add the songs to the playlist but it is adding the only one song to the playlist and that one song is updated to all other playlists i.e. if am adding one song to playlist_1 ...that is also added to playlist_2 and rest others.

**I want to add multiple songs to playlist and those songs should not add be added in other playlist if i am not adding it
please help me thank you:) **

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from .models import Song,Playlist
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your views here.


def home_view(request):
    songs=Song.objects
    return render(request,'home.html',{'songs':songs})



def allplaylists_view(request):
    playlists=Playlist.objects
    currentuser=request.user
    return render(request,'allplaylists.html',{'playlists':playlists, 'currentuser':currentuser})

def playlistsongs_view(request):
    playlists=Playlist.objects.all()
    playlistName=request.GET.get('name')
    return render(request,'playlistsongs.html',{'playlists':playlists, 'playlistName':playlistName})

def createplaylist_view(request):
    songs=Song.objects
    if request.method == 'POST':
        playlist=Playlist()
        playlist.list_name=request.POST['playlistname']
        playlist.user=request.user
        playlist.save()
        print(playlist.list_name,playlist.user)
        return render(request,'addsongs.html',{'songs':songs})
else:
    return render(request,'createplaylist.html',{'songs':songs})

def addsongs_view(request,pk):
    songs=Song.objects.all()
    playlist=Playlist.objects
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item=Song.objects.get(id=pk)
        playlist.song=item
        Playlist.objects.update(song=item)
        return render(request,'addsongs.html',{'songs':songs})
        return render(request,'addsongs.html',{'songs':songs})
```

urls.py-----> (it is not of accounts ...that working fine)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from boom import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
    path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
    path('allplaylists/',views.allplaylists_view,name='allplaylists'),
    path('playlistsongs/',views.playlistsongs_view,name='playlistsongs'),
    path('createplaylist/',views.createplaylist_view,name='createplaylist'),
    path('createplaylist/<int:pk>',views.addsongs_view,name='addsongs'),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the Playlist to Song  relation from ForeignKey to [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) field:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    list_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    songs=models.ManyToManyField(Song)
```

And add multiple songs like this:

```
def createplaylist_view(request):
    songs=Song.objects
    if request.method == 'POST':
        playlist=Playlist()
        playlist.list_name=request.POST['playlistname']
        playlist.user=request.user
        playlist.save()
        print(playlist.list_name,playlist.user)
        playlist.songs.add(*songs)  # <-- here
        return render(request,'addsongs.html',{'songs':songs})
else:
    return render(request,'createplaylist.html',{'songs':songs})
```

FYI, please consider using [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/) to store data.

Answer (score 1):

You've got your answer but lemme explain why you should use *ManyToMany* (*m2m*) and not *ForeignKey* (*FK*)

It's simply because a *Song* can exist in many *Playlists* and a *Playlist* can have many *Songs*.

The `FK` thing you've done says something else which is: A *Playlist* can have only one *song* (it's a key for the playlist!) and a *Song* can exist in many *Playlists* which is, many playlists that have only one song, you don't want that.

FYI: You should use forms if this is an HTML template that needs renders, and you can use [Django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) if it's a stateless API.